# ajax to php undefined index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ive seen questions like this but none of the answers seem to work for me. Im trying to send POST data to a separate php file that would insert it into a database. I get a PHP notice: undefined index arg1 and arg2.....Here is the ajax:

```
function performAjaxSubmission() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'likedata.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {
            'action': 'save',
            'arg1': '<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'];?>', 
            'arg2': '<?php echo $p;?>'

          },
          success: function() {
            alert("success!");
          }
        });
        return false; // <--- important, prevents the link's href (hash in this example) from executing.
      }

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(".icon-thumbs-up").click(performAjaxSubmission);
      });
```

and here is the likedata.php

```
if(isset($_POST)){
$liker = $_POST['arg1'];
$likee = $_POST['arg2'];

$profile->insertLikes($liker, $likee);


}
```

thanks!

Comment: print_r($_POST); is it populated correctly?

Comment: Give arg1 and arg2 a static value and see the result for clues.

Comment: Some other debugging steps: `var_dump` your values in the original PHP files sending, are the values actually being put into javascript correctly (the `$_SESSION` value etc)? IF they look okay in the php-side, look in the browser source before the AJAX is sent, do the values appear correctly there, any JS errors? If that is fine then send the form and use Firebug etc to look at what it sends, do the values appear in the outgoing POST? (Sounds like no from your previous reply, but maybe something is triggering it twice and last call is empty, stranger things have happened)

Comment: Thanks yeah I gave them numeric values but it is still empty

Answer (score 0):

```
        'arg1': "<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'];?>", 
        'arg2': "<?php echo $p;?>"
```

You have single quotes inside single quotes without escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("likedata.php",{
'arg1': "<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'];?>", 
'arg2': "<?php echo $p;?>"postaction:'action' },
function(data){
  .
  .
  .
},'json');
```